# Prevent unique permissions being created after approving access request

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, inheritance

I realize similar questions have been asked, but I haven't found an exact answer to my question yet.
We have a Sharepoint Online environment with multiple sites. When people try to access a site they don't have access to, they can send in an access request. This is sent to the site owners who can approve or reject it. This is all normal.
However, lately I've found that when people send in an access request from a specific page, the request is only for that particular page, So when an owner approves the request, the inheritence is broken and the page gets unique permissions. I know I can remove unique permissions on any page, but with multiple sites to manage, used by thousands of people, this is not a permanent solution.
I need to disable the breaking of inheritance as I always want all content on the site to have the same permissions. I've already set the sharing permissions to site owners only, but they might send out links to specific pages too.

Is there a way to make sure inheritance is never broken and so access requests are always about the entire site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is NO.

This is how access request works, it allows people to request access to content that they do not currently have permission to see.

We cannot limit access requests to the site only, if users send in an access request from a specific page, it's also by design that they will get the unique permission different from the site.

Comment: I was afraid that would be the answer. This way over time you would have no way of knowing who has access to which content apart from checking the permissions of every single page and file one by one. Thanks for your input anyway.